# How to add two logos on frame title in rmarkdown beamer presentation?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, beamer

I have the following rmardown beamer presentation `presentation.rmd`:

````
---
title: "Markdown beamer with to logos"
output: 
beamer_presentation:
    slide_level: 1
    theme: "Berkeley"
header-includes: |
\pgfdeclareimage[height=.5cm, width=1.5cm]{logoMyCompany}{data/img/logoMyCompany.png}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=.5cm, width=1.5cm]{logoMyCompany}{data/img/logoOurClient.png}

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

# First page title
````

[image]

I want to add two companies logos on the TOP RIGHT side on the slide (in frame titles on each frame).

How do I do that.

I use `Berkeley` `beamer` theme which I would like to keep, if possible.

I know how to add logo in top left coner:

```
\pgfdeclareimage[height=.5cm, width=1.5cm]{logo}{data/img/logo.png}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}}
```

But in this case it is not suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as many logos as you want in the `\logo{}` macro:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\pgfdeclareimage[height=.5cm]{logoHarman}{example-image-duck}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=.5cm]{logoMSC}{example-image-duck}

\logo{\pgfuseimage{logoMSC}\pgfuseimage{logoHarman}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

and in rmarkdown:

````
---
title: "Markdown beamer with to logos"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    slide_level: 1
    theme: "Berkeley"
header-includes: 
  - \pgfdeclareimage[height=.5cm]{logoHarman}{example-image-duck}
  - \pgfdeclareimage[height=.5cm]{logoMSC}{example-image-duck}
  - \logo{\pgfuseimage{logoMSC}\pgfuseimage{logoHarman}}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

# First page title
````

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not what I want. I mistakenly asked how to add logos in the top left side, but I need it in the top right, side by side on each slide. `logo{}` macro seems not suitable.

Comment: And I also need `rmarkdown` solution not plain `latex`

Comment: @Alexander To position the logo at the right site see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93809/place-two-logo-on-top-right-and-top-left-in-beamer-presentation It does not matter that you are using rmarkdown, you could add `\logo{..}` or the redefinitions from the linked question in your header included, just as you do with the `\pgfdeclareimage`